# QT Creator - LNK2019 and LNK1120 errors

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, compilation

Hello I've just downloaded and installed QT Creator.
I had made project and I tried to Compile it.
Compiling had ended and I recieved two errors and one warning:

[image]

I've read something about that on this forum I found that I should do:
Build/Clean All and after that Build/Run qmake
It was helpful for most of people but not for me.
What should I do to solve this problem. I really would like to learn QT :|

PS. I didn't change anything in generated code in the new project. And my compiler is 64-bit.

Comment: Please provide more details about the peoject: code and .pro file

Answer (score 0):

Installing Qt Creator will not allow you to compile your project. Qt creator is an IDE only.
You have to have a kit (compiler + Qt libraries) installed on your computer. If you are new to Qt and if you are trying to compile your code on a PC (Windows), you should try to install Qt using the online installer available on https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/.

Comment: I've downloaded qt creator from there.

Comment: What is your environment (OS, compiler, Qt library)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your defined class is listed as a source file in your .pro file, then try running QMake again (build -> run qmake), THEN try to build. You can also try cleaning/rebuilding your project after editing yout .pro file.